# Why Angular app http requests hang after about 20 requests to different ASP.NET Core endpoints are made?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

## What is it

1. Angular front-end app served via nginx on the server or cordova on android
2. ASP.NET Core back-end, which connects to MySQL database via Pomelo connector. On production back-end app is served through nginx reverse proxy.

## Problem

Requests sent from the Angular app to api take long time (a minute or more) or completely timeout after around 20-50 requests on production (on my local dev environment with IIS server this may happen a couple times a day, sometimes doesn't happen at all for several days).

Maybe this can give someone a clue. I thought that the problem is with EF queries since I retrieve an entity with its children entities (picture, comments, likes, other business-related entities). *But when I close angular app and open again - requests again work fine for the next 20-50 of them.*

I also assume that this may be because of DbContext issue, which I was told about by one developer.

## Where it happens

Both on the dev and prod environment. However, on production it occurs sooner. The production server has 1GB RAM and relatively slow CPU ($5 Digital Ocean droplet).

## What I tried

1. Rewritten EF queries according to the best practices described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#:%7E:text=Do%20minimize%20network%20round%20trips,no%2Dtracking%20queries%20more%20efficiently)

Comment: Maybe start with optimizing API using Postman as test tool. I believe Angular is not the problem in this case.

Comment: @RoarS. I ran Postman tests. 2670 were within 1 second. 24 within 2 seconds. 1 almost 7 seconds. The test was 15 typical for angular app calls for 100 iterations without delay. API was the production one. While in angular app it hangs for 5 seconds and above that.

Comment: Then you have verified that your API is performing well. Can you as a next step set up an Angular end-point that does nothing but getting data from API?

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @RoarS. thank you for directing me. Filtered back-end out I realized that the bottleneck could be in my RxJs extensions in the Angular app. I checked them and it turned out that notifications polling observable created every time I navigate to a new route. After 20-50 navigation events there are 20-50 polling requests which block everything. Polling mechanism re-write fixed the issue.

Comment: Great corrective action.  Congratulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtered back-end out I realized that the bottleneck could be in my RxJs extensions in the Angular app. I checked them and it turned out that notifications polling observable is created every time I navigate to a new route. After 20-50 navigation events there are 20-50 polling requests which block everything. Polling mechanism re-write fixed the issue.